# Why is the Data Export Tab empty

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Setup : Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

mySql Workbench : 8.0.25 - installed via SNAP

I've been using mySql Workbench for a long time, but recently the Data Export tab has started appearing blank, like this :

[image]

Clicking "Advanced Options" gives this :

[image]

I've tried reinstalling from Snap - no change in behaviour.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were able to resolve this? I stuck with same issue and tried clean reinstall couple of times but no luck.

Comment: @Prajwol : Did you see my answer below? In my case it was down to the virus checker software ( ESET ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this if qualifies as a "fix" - but the problem appears to be due to the ESET anti virus software running on my machine.

The problem is described [here](https://forum.eset.com/topic/7097-log-in-show-ldso-object-libesets_pacso-from-etcldsopreload-cannot-be-preloaded-ignored/), and my "solution" was to just delete the entry from `/etc/ld.so.preload`

I have no idea what effect that has had on my virus checker ( but the license has run out anyway )